# Convert pandas column of lists to a python set

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a pandas column of lists, for example

```
column1
['a', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'e']
['b', 'e', 'g']
```

How do I convert this into a python set?

for example

```
print(pythonSet)
> {'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'g'}
```

I tried doing `set(df['column1'])` but that results in an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short and sweet:

```
{*df['column1'].sum()}
# {'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'g'}
```

The idea is to flatten your column of lists into a single iterable first. For python <= 3.5 please use `set(...)` instead of the unpacking operator `{*...}`.

---

Better in terms of performance:

```
from itertools import chain
{*chain.from_iterable(df['column1'])
# {'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'g'}
```

---

Also good from in terms of performance - a nested list comprehension (but `chain` is marginally faster):

```
{y for x in df['column1'] for y in x}
# {'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'g'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `pandas` version 0.25 or more you can do:

```
print(set(df["column1"].explode()))
```

Output:

```
{'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'g'}
```